# GORM / Hibernate Not Creating Correct INSERT Statement

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Grails 2.2.4

I'm not sure why, because this was working and then just stopped kind of out of nowhere. I have the following domain:

```
class ProjectDocument extends Auditable {
  Integer externalId
  String name
  Boolean completed = false
  Boolean purchased = false
  Boolean modifiedAfterPublish = true
  Integer revisionNumber
  String registrationNumber
  User documenter
  User fieldTechnician
  User registrant
  User enforcementAgent
  Date enforcementDateChecked
  PublishedDocument document
  Employer enforcementOrg
  ProjectDocumentEntry currentEntryCursor

  static belongsTo = [
    project : Project
  ]

  static hasMany = [
      projectDocumentEntries: ProjectDocumentEntry
  ]

  static constraints = {
    name nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 50
    purchased nullable: false
    externalId nullable: false
    completed nullable: false
    revisionNumber nullable: false
    registrationNumber nullable: true, blank: false, maxSize: 50, unique: true
    enforcementDateChecked nullable: true
    project nullable: true
    document nullable: false
    enforcementOrg nullable: true
    documenter nullable: true
    fieldTechnician nullable: true
    registrant nullable: true
    enforcementAgent nullable: true
    modifiedAfterPublish nullable: true
    currentEntryCursor nullable: true
  }
}
```

This is the Auditable domain:

```
abstract class Auditable implements Serializable {

  Date dateCreated
  Date lastUpdated
  User createdBy
  User modifiedBy

  static constraints = {
    dateCreated nullable: true
    lastUpdated nullable: true
    createdBy nullable: false
    modifiedBy nullable: false
  }
}
```

When I try and insert data into this table, I am getting the following SQL:

```
insert 
    into
        project_document
        (version, completed, created_by_id, current_entry_cursor_id, date_created, document_id, documenter_id, enforcement_agent_id, enforcement_date_checked, enforcement_org_id, external_id, field_technician_id, last_updated, modified_after_publish, modified_by_id, name, purchased, registrant_id, registration_number, revision_number) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Note the lack of a `project_id` column. And for this reason, I'm getting this error:

```
Field 'project_id' doesn't have a default value
```

Steps I've taken to resolve the issue but didn't resolve the issue:

- `grails clean`
- removed .grails/2.2.4/projects/
- Made project nullable: true
- dumped the database and recreated it
- verified I'm getting an appropriate Project associated to the domain prior to save()
- I've also tried project.addToProjectDocuments() but that gives me an invalid argument error

I'm really at a loss as to why this is what seems to be suddenly not working.

UPDATE: I refactored the name of the Domain to ProjectDocumentFix to see if it would work, and low and behold, it works. So there is something somewhere messed with with project_document / ProjectDocument and I don't know what it might be.

To make matters even stranger, this is not only happening on my local machine, but in our staging environment as well.

Comment: Is `Auditable` in `src/groovy` or `grails-app/domain`?

Comment: It is in src/groovy.

Comment: Are you saving Project and ProjectDocument save is cascaded? Can you also add Project domain? Did anyone (DBA most likely) modify the sequence for Project? Was the generator strategy for Project modified? Can you also add the SQL query where Project is persisted and/or fetched?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have no idea why this was the issue, but in our Project domain, I noticed the following:

```
List<ProjectDocument> getProjectDocuments() {
  ProjectDocument.findAllByProject(this)
}
```

Which makes no sense because we also have this:

```
static hasMany = [
  projectDocuments: ProjectDocument  
]
```

Removing the getter solved the issue.